# How can I add an enable signal to a 3-Phase H-Bridge?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, h-bridge, enable

How can I add a signal to turn off or disable a 3-Phase H-Bridge? I have thought about adding a P-channel MOSFET controlled by a signal called Enable to open the voltage source of the bridge or a N-Channel one to open the circuit in the ground part. Would this configurations work? Three MOSFETS vertically, like that, would they switch? Which configuration is better?

[image]

Comment: What drivers are you using the H-bridge? These usually have enable signals you could use directly. What are you hoping to achieve with the enable signal? What power, current and voltages are you handeling? What time of swithes are you using? FETS? IGBTs?

Comment: I need to enable/disable the bridge especifically, not the driver, avoiding failures there. The voltage is 12V and 3 or 5V for the enable signal.